# How to auto select checkbox in Expandable view Android

Tags: android, checkbox, expandablelistview

I am able to get selected check box value in Expandable view. Now I want to auto selected these check box again if their value exists in array.

I am getting clicked checkbox value as pair(groipId, childId). So when user click edit, I want these check box auto select. All of my data coming from some API.

This is the code for getting select box value.

```
    final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childCkBox);
    // add tag to remember groupId/childId
    final Pair<Long, Long> tag = new Pair<Long, Long>(
            getGroupId(groupPosition),
            getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition));

    cb.setTag(tag);
    // set checked if groupId/childId in checked items
    cb.setChecked(mCheckedItems.contains(tag));
    // set OnClickListener to handle checked switches
    cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
            final Pair<Long, Long> tag = (Pair<Long, Long>) v.getTag();
            if (cb.isChecked()) {
                mCheckedItems.add(tag);
            } else {
                mCheckedItems.remove(tag);
            }
        }
    });
    txtListChild.setText(childText);

    public Set<Pair<Long, Long>> getCheckedItems() {
     return mCheckedItems;
    }
```

Editing and suggesting are welcome.

Edit 1: I am storing selected check box value to server. So when I edit them, I can `pre select` previous selected boxes using previous values.

Comment: looks like you already have it, what is the question exactly?

Comment: @TimCastelijns When I click edit, I want all my selected group auto select next time whenever I edit them

Comment: Try passing data structure for check-status into the ELV `adapter` constructor and store a reference. Use reference in `getChildView` to determine a call to `setChecked` on `checkbox`.

Comment: The most straightforward way is by position, but if that doesn't work, you could encode child's id into the check-status data structure (ie a `List<int, bool>`).

Comment: Ok... will try this as u said

Comment: I was going to type ya something up earlier but I got hit with a stack of bug fixes. I've got a partial solution, I'll try to finish it in morning.

Comment: @samusarin I am waiting for your responce